# How to Convert Pandas Dataframe to Keras RNN for Multivariate classification Problems

Tags: python, pandas, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to make a recurrent neural network model. Could anyone explain to me how can we convert pandas dataframe to sequence?

I check several places and all the places it explains only, how RNN works with simple arrays, not with pandas dataframe. My target variable is the "Label" column and it does have 5 variables.

Below is my code and it getting an error when I try to do model.fit. I attached an image here to check.

```
import numpy
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)

AllDataSelFeLabEncDataframe
    Flow_IAT_Max    Fwd_IAT_Std   Pkt_Len_Max   Fwd_Pkt_Len_Std   Label
0   591274.0        11125.35538   32             0.0                3
1   633973.0        12197.74612   32             0.0                3
2   591242.0        12509.82212   32             0.0                3
3   2.0             0.0           0              0.0                2
4   1.0             0.0           0              0.0                2
5   460.0           0.000000      0              0.000000           1
6   10551.0         311.126984    326            188.216188         1
7   476.0           0.000000      0              0.000000           1
8   4380481.0       2185006.405   935            418.144712         0
9   4401241.0       2192615.483   935            418.144712         0
10  3364844.0       1675797.985   935            418.144712         0
11  4380481.0       2185006.405   935            418.144712         0
12  43989.0         9929.900528    0             0.0                4

# define y variable, i.e., what I want to predict
y_col='Label' 

X = AllDataSelFeLabEnc.drop(y_col,axis=1).copy()
y = AllDataSelFeLabEnc[[y_col]].copy() 
# the double brakets here are to keep the y in dataframe format, otherwise it will be pandas Series
print(X.shape,y.shape)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.30, random_state=1)

length = 500


n_input = 25 #how many samples/rows/timesteps to look in the past in order to forecast the next sample
n_features= X_train.shape[1] # how many predictors/Xs/features we have to predict y
b_size = 32 # Number of timeseries samples in each batch


# create the model
embedding_vecor_length = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(5000, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=length))
model.add(LSTM(150, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input, n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())


model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)

[![Error I'm getting][1]][1]


# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))


y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Print the confusion matrix
print(metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))

# Print the precision and recall, among other metrics
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred, digits=3))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the keras documentation for LSTM

> inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature].

so in your case what is needed is [32, 25, 4] or [n_features, n_input, n_features]

I don't think this kind of prepresentation is possible with a dataframe, unless the input data is turned into a array of Dataframe**s**.

So here is way to do it with numpy which I believe is the easiest and also efficient way-

```py
# .loc includes the last element too, so we subtract 1
# the math handles the end case. When the data samples are not a multiple of timestamps you a want to use in a shot 
x = X_train.loc[:(len(X_train)//n_input)*n_input-1, INPUT_FEATURES].to_numpy()
X_train = np.reshape(x, (len(X_train)//n_input, n_input, n_features))
```

### Note

The code above doesn't perform rolling window, instead window slices i.e., if you have 50 samples, you get only 2 samples instead of 26 samples 1-25, 2-26, 3-27 and so on 26-50